# Why I have to cast void pointer to int pointer before using its value?

Tags: c, pointers, casting

So I came across this situation today. I had a code like this

```
void some_handler(some_stuct_t * p_evt_type)
{   
            uint16_t a = ((uint16_t )p_evt_type->p_instance->p_instance_handler);
            (a)++;
}
```

It was givinig me warnings, but when I changed code to cast to pointer it looks like perfectly correct.

```
void some_handler(some_stuct_t * p_evt_type)
{   
            uint16_t * a = ((uint16_t *)p_evt_type->p_instance->p_instance_handler);
            (*a)++;
}
```

The

```
p_instance_handler
```

is of type

```
(void *)
```

What is wrong with casting directly to value ?

Comment: Means? You want to cast a pointer to an `uint16_t`?

Comment: Noo, I wanted to cast memory it pointing to to uint16_t. I already see that this could not work, thanks!

Comment: Note that in C you don't need to cast when assigning to/from `void*` from/to other data pointer types. `uint16_t * a = p_evt_type->p_instance->p_instance_handler;` should work fine.

Comment: Right, but it looks more clear to me. Still, thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ## [INT36-C. Converting a pointer to integer or integer to pointer](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/INT36-C.+Converting+a+pointer+to+integer+or+integer+to+pointer)
>
> Conversions between integers and pointers can have undesired
>   consequences depending on the
>   [implementation](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/BB.+Definitions#BB.Definitions-implementation).
>   According to the C Standard, subclause 6.3.2.3 [[ISO/IEC
>   9899:2011](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/AA.+Bibliography#AA.Bibliography-ISO-IEC9899-2011)],
>
> > An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously
> >     specified, the result is implementation-defined, might not be
> >     correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced
> >     type, and might be a trap representation.
>
> > Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as
> >     previously specified, the result is implementation-defined. If the
> >     result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behavior is
> >     undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any
> >     integer type.

In short, conversion between pointers and integers is possible but the result is implementation-defined, so in implementations where `sizeof(integer) < sizeof(pointer)` the conversion will not work.

> **Noncompliant Code Example**
>
> The size of a pointer can be greater than the size of an integer, such as in an implementation where pointers are 64 bits and unsigned integers are 32 bits.
>
> ```
> void f(void) {
>   char *ptr;
>   /* ... */
>   unsigned int number = (unsigned int)ptr;
>   /* ... */
> }
> ```

Comment: Downvoted: Pointers are *not* necessarily the same size on the same machine (N1570 6.2.5 p28). Of pointer to basic types only `void*` and any `char*` have that property. Second example works because there is a **conversion** from `void*` to `uint16_t*` inserted by the compiler if it's needed on that particular platform.

Comment: @user694733 I agree, fixed it now.

Comment: Unfortunately *"since they're both pointers, and all pointers have the same size in the program."* is still incorrect. Size of the pointers is irrelevant. `void*` to `uint16_t*` assignment works, because conversion is well defined (N1570 6.3.2.3 p1).

Comment: @user694733 what about the size in case of casting to an integer like [here](http://ideone.com/1A7EFO) ?

Comment: Conversions between pointer and integer are allowed (6.3.2.3 p5-6), but the result is implementation defined, or in the worst case, undefined. So size does come into play here. If contents of the pointer can be represented in integer type, then conversion *can* be legal on some systems.

Comment: @user694733 okay, it's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

While there is no need to cast a pointer from *type to void* or *void to type* (with some limited exceptions not relevant here), the cast becomes of critical importance when you need to derefernce a `void` pointer. As you know a pointer stores as its value the address of something else. When dealing with pointers of the same type as the value, there are no need for any additional casts as the `type` has already been fixed. e.g.

```
int a[] = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
int *ap = a;
ap++;
printif (" ap points to : %d\n", *ap);
```

All good, no mystery. Now lets take a function that will iterate over the values in the array taking the array and number of elements as its parameters. But there is still another parameter needed to be able to iterate over the array passed as `void *`. What is it? The *sizeof* each element that make sup `a`.

Otherwise, since the array was passed as a void pointer, what would happen to *pointer arithmetic*? In the function, what would happen if we attempted `ap++`?

Therein lies the issue. When handling pointers as void pointers, they are very convenient to use, but when the values they hold must be manipulated, they must be cast so that the compiler knows size of the object pointed to, so it can know how many bytes exist between `ap` and the next value in your array located at `ap++`.

There is another caveat in type casting pointers. They must be cast in such a way that rules of *strict aliasing* are not violated and that *type punning* does not occur. See [**C11 N1570 Committee Draft — April 12, 2011**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html) For that your will want to take a look at sections 6.5 (6) and (7) paying close attention to the notes included on the draft as well. Without going into the loopholes and qualifications, you can safely cast a void pointer to its *effective type* or to *char*. Any other combination is asking for an aliasing violation resulting in a type punned pointer.

So continuing with our example, if we were to pass our array `a` to a function as `void *` instead of `int *`, what would be required in our function to allow pointer arithmetic to work properly? We know from rule 6.5 (6) that we can cast to `char` and not run afoul of the strict-aliasing rules, so we may be able to handle it like this, where `a` is our array, `n` the number of elements, and `sz` the size of each element in the array:

```
void prnarray (void *a, size_t n, size_t sz)
{
    char *ap = a;
    printf ("\npointers printed from prnarray:\n\n");
    while (n--) {
        printf (" ap points to : %d\n", *ap);
        ap += sz;
    }
}
```

We can then step through the array without problem while adding the appropriate size/offset from each prior element.

What if we know we will be taking an array of `int` through the `void` pointer? That allows a cast directly to the *effective type* of the array and we no longer need to worry about passing the size. Pointer arithmetic will take care of the offset to/from each value within the array, e.g.

```
 void prnarrayint (void *a, size_t n)
{
    int *ap = a;
    printf ("\npointers printed from prnarrayint:\n\n");
    while (n--)
        printf (" ap points to : %d\n", *ap++);
}
```

While not as flexible as the previous function, where we were not limited to the type, there are many circumstances where you will know the type of pointer you are getting passed as void, and in those instances, casting to the *effective type* will simplify your code.

Now putting all the pieces together you could create a short illustrative example something as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void prnarray (void *a, size_t n, size_t sz)
{
    char *ap = a;
    printf ("\npointers printed from prnarray:\n\n");
    while (n--) {
        printf (" ap points to : %d\n", *ap);
        ap += sz;
    }
}

void prnarrayint (void *a, size_t n)
{
    int *ap = a;
    printf ("\npointers printed from prnarrayint:\n\n");
    while (n--)
        printf (" ap points to : %d\n", *ap++);
}

int main (void) {

    int a[] = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
    int *ap = a;
    size_t i, n = sizeof a/ sizeof *a;
    i = n;

    printf ("\npointers printed in main:\n\n");
    while (i--)
        printf (" ap points to : %d\n", *ap++);

    prnarray (a, n, sizeof *a);  /* pass/print based on sz with cast to char */

    prnarrayint (a, n);  /* pass/print based on effective type of array */

    return 0;
}
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/voidpcast

pointers printed in main:

 ap points to : 1
 ap points to : 3
 ap points to : 5
 ap points to : 7
 ap points to : 9

pointers printed from prnarray:

 ap points to : 1
 ap points to : 3
 ap points to : 5
 ap points to : 7
 ap points to : 9

pointers printed from prnarrayint:

 ap points to : 1
 ap points to : 3
 ap points to : 5
 ap points to : 7
 ap points to : 9
```

So in summary, the universal pointer `void` can be assigned to/from any type pointer and back without the need of a cast, however when any operation requires the pointer to be dereferenced to obtain the value pointed to, then an appropriate cast must be made to either its *effective type* or *char* in order to comply with the rules of *strict-aliasing*.